# 2D array matrix output

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I would like to print out Z[X][Y] values in a matrix in csv format, and I got an error. How can I print out Z[X][Y] in normal print () function?

Here is my code snippet:

```
    Z[X][Y] = [((20-10)/99)*(X-1)+10 for X in range(1, 101) for Y in range(1, 2)]
    Z[X][Y] = [((20-10)/99)*(Y-1)+10 for Y in range(1, 101) for X in range(1, 2)]
    Z[X][Y] = [((60-20)/99)*(X-1)+20 for X in range(1, 101) for Y in range(100, 101)]
    Z[X][Y] = [((60-20)/99)*(Y-1)+20 for Y in range(1, 101) for Y in range(100, 101)]
```

Here is the error message:

> IndexError: list index out of range

My plan is to write a double for loop to output a 2D matrix in csv file. I am expecting a 100 rows and 100 columns matrix. Here is idea for double for loop:

```
for X in range (1, 101):
    for Y in range (1, 101):
        Z[X][1] = ((20-10)/99)*(X-1)+10
        Z[1][Y] = ((20-10)/99)*(Y-1)+10
        Z[X][100] = ((60-20)/99)*(X-1)+20
        Z[100][Y] = ((60-20)/99)*(Y-1)+20
```

Comment: Where do you define Z? Anyway indexes are from `0-99` and not from `1-100`

Comment: I would like Z[X][Y] from (X=1, Y=1) to (X=100, Y=100) like a square matrix.

Comment: Again, indexes starts from 0 and not from 1. So Z[X][1] should be Z[X][0] and so on. You can create a bigger matrix to simulate that it starts with 1, but you should define it to be of size [101,101] and not [100,100]

Comment: I would like Z[X][Y] from (X=1, Y=1) to (X=100, Y=100) like a square matrix.
(1, 100) ... (100, 100)
...
(1, 1) ...     (100, 1)

Z[1][1] = 10
Z[100][1] = 20
Z[1][100] = 20
Z[100][100] = 60

Answer (score 0):

If you have the 2D matrix ready in `Z` variable you can print that matrix in CSV format using below code

```
#Example of 2D matrix in Z variable
#Below is the example code to create 10x10 2D matrix
Z=[[Y for y in range(1,11)] for X in range(0,10)]

# Print matrix in CSV format
for X in range(len(Z)):
    print(",".join(map(str, Z[X])))
```